# SwiftUI - struct embedded in struct with UUID()

Tags: swift, struct, swiftui

Using `SwiftUI`, I have a `embedded struct` in a `struct` like

```
   struct Order Identifiable {
       var id = UUID()
       var includeSoap: Bool = false
       var includeTowel : Bool = false
       var quantity : Int
   }

   struct CompletedOrder Identifiable {
       // var id = UUID() or var id = order.id
       var order : Order
       var summary : String
       var purchaseDate : String
   }
```

For later use I need to use the `Identifiable` keyword.

How do I avoid the extra UUID()? I can try to copy the Order.id to the CompletedOrder.id but not sure if it is a bug in XCode but I got weird errors there.

Anyway, what is the best way to do this? Do I need in both structs `'Identifiable'` or is there a kind of inheritaence? What are the pro and cons about this? Again I got weird results in XCode. But I hope its me ;)

Thank you

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? same UUID with the order? Show an example of what you desire.

Comment: I would like to reuse the `Order struct` in the `CompletedOrder struct` to avoid copy and typing errors. For building some test's I guess its okay to have the same id double, but later I would like, when the Order is full-filled, to remove the Order.id and only keep the CompletedOrder.id. So, I like to use the code from you (M.Hosseini) `var id: UUID { order.id }` and then remove the Order.id, but how to setup a closure? Something like `didset` for CompletedOrder var id?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it. SwiftUI is new, XCode is buggy, I'am new to Swift. Why the -2? Was this a silly question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

return the `order.id` it self:

```
struct CompletedOrder: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID { order.id }
    var order: Order
    var summary: String
    var purchaseDate: String
}
```

Comment: Thank you. was messing with the assignment =